# Is there a way to vary the value of "RepeatColumn" property of Datalist according to width in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, datalist

I have this datalist which has its propert  `RepeatColumns` value set to 3.I am working in a responsive design now.Is there a way to vary this value to say 2.When i have to display in smalled display device i have to small screen size so i'll be able to display just two columns per row.

```
<asp:DataList ID="dl2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="3" >
```

Comment: No. It is a server control, it is processed on the server which has no way to determine what the current width of the browser on the client.

Comment: @BenRobinson SO is there a way to auto assign the number of columns depending upon the size availabel.

Comment: You can set the number of columns based on whatever criteria you choose, so long as that information can be determined on the server.  I don't know what you mean by "the size available", if you mean dynamically adjust output based on the available screen space, then like all responsive design, this is something you do using CSS and javascript in the browser, not in a server side control.

Comment: What i mean is, if the screen size is say 980px i need to display 3 items in a row so i would do `RepeatColumn="3"`.And if the screen size is say 768px, then 3 items won't fit.So i such case i need to render only 2 colums per row.ie `RepeatColumn="2"`.I hope the scenerio is clear now.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but as I said the server has no idea what the screen resolution of the client is, you can't do that in a server control.

Answer (score 3):

You should write  `RepeatLayout="Flow"` property on datalist and don't write the `repeat-column` property.

```
<asp:DataList ID="dl2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left"
              RepeatDirection="Horizontal"  RepeatLayout="Flow" >
```